# A sharp version of Scott core thorem for 3-manifolds

Tags: reference-request, 3-manifolds

Let $M$ be an open $3$-manifold with finitely generated fundamental group. Does $M$ contain a compact codimension zero submanifold whose inclusion into $M$ is a homotopy equivalence?

Somehow I thought this should follow from [Scott core theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_core_theorem), but after some searching I cannot find the statement anywhere. I do not want to assume anything else about $M$, e.g. $M$ may contain two-sided projective planes. In fact, in this generality I do not even see this stated anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, no, because $M$ might be homeomorphic to this core but with an infinite discrete set removed.  You can also do more complicate things, e.g., remove Whitehead continua instead of removing isolated points.

However, $\pi_2$ is the only obstruction to homotopy equivalence.  I cannot think of anything else rigorous to say, but I could imagine that somehow every counterexample can be constructed as a combination of simply connected non-compact regions, and a manifold which is homotopy equivalent to the core.

Comment: Isn't it that you just have to assume that both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are finitely generated to make the conclusion of the statement true?

Comment: Given the sphere theorem, I would suppose so, yes.

Comment: What would be the reference under the assumption that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are finitely generated?

Comment: For example, Theorem 3.2 in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X72900232 shows that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a compact $3$-manifold if and only if $\pi_1(M)$ and the image of the Hurewicz homomorphism in degree $2$ are finitely generated, but it assumes that $M$ has no embedded $RP^2$, and the conslusion is slightly weaker than I want.

Comment: To be clear, a natural hypothesis might be for $\pi_2$ to be finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$-module rather than as an abelian group.   (Because the latter would be too strict.)  Hence the use of the Hurewicz homomorphism in the reference that Igor found.